# Can Residual Nets skip one linearity instead of two?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, deep-residual-networks

Standard in ResNets is to skip 2 linearities.
Would skipping only one work as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would refer you to [the original paper](https://www.cv-foundation.org/openaccess/content_cvpr_2016/papers/He_Deep_Residual_Learning_CVPR_2016_paper.pdf) by Kaiming He at al.

In sections 3.1-3.2, they define "identity" shortcuts as `y = F(x, W) + x`, where `W` are the trainable parameters, **for any residual mapping** `F` to be learned. It is important that the residual mapping contains a *non-linearity*, otherwise the whole construction is one sophisticated linear layer. But the number of linearities is not limited.

For example, [ResNeXt network](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1611.05431.pdf) creates identity shortcuts around a stack of only convolutional layers (see the figure below). So there aren't *any* dense layers in the residual block.

[image: res-next-blocks]

The general answer is, thus: yes, it would work. However, in a particular neural network, reducing two dense layers to one may be a bad idea, because anyway the residual block must be flexible enough to learn the residual function. So remember to validate any design you come up with.